# Is there now, or was there a few years ago, a ferry from Busan, Korea or Shimonoseki, Japan to China?

Tags: japan, china, south-korea, ferries

In the past I took ferries between South Korea and Japan six times, but the most recent was seven years ago.

I seem to recall that besides the Japanese and Korean travellers that there were also many Chinese in the ferry terminal.

I thought this would've been the Busan terminal, but maybe it was the Shimonoseki terminal. I also seem to recall that the Chinese side was Qingdao, but I don't trust my memory completely.

I know there are ferries from Incheon and Osaka to China, but for this question I'm not asking about those since that info is easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E9%96%A2%E5%B8%82#%E6%B5%B7%E9%81%8B), there is a twice-weekly ferry service between Shimonoseki and Suzhou, China, operated by the [Suzhou Shimonoseki Ferry company](http://www.ssferry.co.jp/index.html).

A ferry to Qingdao is also listed, however it [ceased operation](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC#%E6%B2%BF%E9%9D%A9) in December 2015 due to low ridership.